# Unable to locate the env file

Tags: environment-variables

So I am trying to use environmental variables in react. So when ever I send my app to some one I can have them view it on their screen with out them having to use any type of server.But I have this error below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgRsr.png)

Also I will show you my env files and my package.json

.env.development
REACT_APP_API_PATH=http://localhost:3200

.env.production
REACT_APP_API_PATH=https://crud-application-x.herokuapp.com

```
"scripts": {
     "start": "env-cmd .env.development react-scripts start",
    "build": "env-cmd .env.production react-scripts build",
    "test": " env-cmd .env.development react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Above is the package.json scripts
and this is the link of my UI
https://crud-application-x.herokuapp.com/getstudents
So this application works only for my development side. This is suppose to be a crud application but if you guys open it you will not see anything. All I want to do is try to put this in to full production so that anyone can access this with out having to run on any server

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `-f` flag before the .env filename

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "env-cmd -f .env.development react-scripts start",
    "build": "env-cmd -f .env.production react-scripts build",
    "test": " env-cmd -f .env.development react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```